# Syntax for fuzzy search in Solr 4

Tags: search, drupal, solr, syntax, fuzzy-search

I have been trying to enable fuzzy searching for our Solr 4.1 powered search but all I can find online is:

1- how to do it in the default lucene query syntax which doesnt help in my case,
2- that dismax does not support it and
3- that edismax is going to or should support it

However, I can't find any documentation of how to use it in edismax querying format, not even on the default edsimax page for query syntax which uses the operator ~ for defining slop factor instead. I did try specifying it in qf parameter as per some links online but that didn't work and I am also assuming here that Solr 4.1 uses edismax by default.

So if someone knows how its supposed to work or if its even supported, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Try adding this fieldType at your schema.xml.

This is case unsensitive and for spanish words, but changing that should work for you too.

```
<fieldType name="text_es_fuzzy" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

After this, when you perform a query just add "~0.5" at the end of the search string. The "0.5" is a custom value you can choose. This value determines how "fuzzy" your search is. When the value is closer to zero the results will be "fuzzier" and viceversa.